# How to find a file which is having same name in multiple folder and copy to target folder

Tags: linux

I am using a command

```
find ../../ -type f -name <filename>.PDF -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-dirctory=<path>;
```

the problem is it doesn't copy all files but only one file. I want to find a file `abc.pdf` which is present on different folders. I need the latest updated file from all these folders. How can I find it and copy to the target folder?

Comment: This _is_ copying all the files, one after the other - but they all have the same name, so later copies overwrite earlier ones. Your command is basically doing `cp dir1/abc.pdf target/ ; cp dir2/abc.pdf target/` - only the last copy will remain.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /DIR -type f -name "WHATEVER.PDF" -exec stat -f "%m %N" {} \; | \
    sort -n | \
    tail -1 | \
    cut -f2- -d" "
```

Gives you the latest `WHATEVER.PDF` (and it's path, via the `stat` output sorted and filtered). I'm leaving the copying part to you.

Comment: Thanks, Ok I want to copy all searched file in target directory. How can I do it? And which directory this file is storing?

Comment: In this command I was using a variable file. But I forgot where was i using it. Actually I created some script for finding files but it was deleted by me via rm -rf command and it is unable to recover.find ../../ -type f -name <filename>.PDF -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-dirctory=<path>;